# How to get the Exact Mail Address from Lotus Notes Document Using Java API?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am using document.getItemValueString("INetSendTo") to get the mail address of recipient exact mail address. But some of the mail document I am getting null value. In any other field the email address will be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you cannot rely on the address fields.  According to the SMTP RFCs, messages are to be delivered to the recipients listed in the RCPT TO command string as specified in RFC821, even if all of the headers (To, Cc, Bcc) in the RFC822 messsage are missing or empty.  There is a configuration option for Domino to create a BlindCopyTo item for any RCPT TO recipient who was not listed in any of the RFC822 headers, but you cannot assume that this option was enabled at the time the message was received.

Answer (score 2):

Email addresses are always stored in the From, SendTo, CopyTo, BlindCopyTo fields.

With certain configurations of the server the corresponding internet email adresses for internal addresses are stored in the INetFrom, INetSendTo, INetCopyTo and INetBlindCopyTo fields.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply... for some documents only I got the null value. For some documents I got the Proper mail id like. user1@corp.company.com....

Comment: Exactly. Whether the INet fields contains a value or not, depends on server configuration and the correct circumstances. You need to check the administration help for info on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. If you are happy with my answer, then please mark your question as answered.